# PHP loop for each row with different style

Tags: php

Can someone help me please?
I need a loop for a checkerboard pattern project.

Right now i have this:

```
<?php
$uitvoer="<table summary=''>\n";    
$j=0; 
$uitvoer .= "\t<tr>\n";
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
{
 $uitvoer .= "\t\t<td class='kleur".(($i+$j)%2)."'>&nbsp;</td>\n";
}    
echo <<<END
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>    
<title>Page title</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
td
{
 width:  50px;
 height: 50px;
 border:4px groove red;
}
td.kleur0
{
 background-color: white;
}
td.kleur1
{
 background-color: black;
}  
-->
</style>    
</head>
<body>
$uitvoer
</body>
</html>
END;
?>
```

Then i get this: 
[image: Situation now]

So far so good.

But i need 8 rows with different lines and colors
The result need to be like this: 
[image: End result should be like this]

How can i do that the easiest and fastest way in a loop or a array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a second loop that adds table rows (`<tr>`). The beginning of your file should look like this:

```
$uitvoer="<table summary=''>\n";

for ($j=0; $j < 8; $j++) {
  $uitvoer .= "\t<tr>\n"; 
  for($i=0;$i<8;$i++) {
   $uitvoer .= "\t\t<td class='kleur".(($i+$j)%2)."'>&nbsp;</td>\n";
  }
  $uitvoer .= "\t</tr>\n"; 
}
```

So, inside the loops, `$i` will hold your table cell (`<td>` tag) and `$j` will hold your table row (`<tr>` tag).